# Поймать действие

Tags: jquery

Задача: Выполнить отправку голосовых сообщений

Есть кнопка "Микрофон", при нажатии на неё записывается голос, при отпускании кнопки выполнятся отправка.

Как поймать клик я знаю (можно использовать onclick), но как поймать событие отпускания кнопки?

Comment: события мыши не ограничиваются одними только `click`-событиями: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mouseup - событие, если кнопка мыши отжата

mousedown - если нажата

```
$(el).bind('mouseup', function() {
   //кнопка отжата 
 })
```

Comment: А что делать с мобильными устройствами? Там это не работает.